# Storybook "does not exist or is not a directory" error in SvelteKit + Vite project

Tags: vite, storybook, sveltekit, pnpm

[image]

Hello! I have a SvelteKit/Vite project and I want to install `Storybook` into it. Folowing the official instructions gives me error like this.
I tried to install it with `npx` as well as with `pnpm`, got the same error. Also deleted the `npm-cache` folder. Still no result. Any suggestions? Not sure what causing that error and how to debug it.